# What is the best word for the wish to learn something? e.g. "Learnwish" (but it doesn't exist, right?)

Tags: american-english, usage, british-english

If you could tell me a word meaning "wish to learn something" then I would be really glad.

Comment: "*Curious*", perhaps?

Comment: *{Thirst / appetite} for {learning / knowledge}.*

Answer (score 3):

*Inquisitiveness*, or *thirst for knowledge*.

As an aside, it's "wish to learn", not "wish to learning". The latter is ungrammatical.

As a further aside, "`" is the [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent). It is a letter part, not a punctuation mark. Do not misuse it as an apostrophe. That's like replacing a b with a d. They might look very similar, but they don't mean remotely the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I have been part of a group that has been once described as

*eager to learn*

You can say we were interns and the working environment seemed relatively new to us. We kept asking questions, reading documentation, reading books... We did our best to rapidly integrate the team and the company as a whole. So the person in charge described us as being *eager to learn*.

When trying to find some reference, the first google result was [https://www.eagertolearn.org/](https://www.eagertolearn.org/Default.aspx)

And you can definitely apply that to a particular subject, as in

> eager to learn Spanish

Answer (score 1):

The most concise representation would be the word *"curiosity"*.